# Why Diamond operator was not missed from Right hand side in Java 7?

Tags: java, generics, diamond-operator

Java 7 has improved the diamond operator

In Java 6:

```java
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

In Java 7:

```java
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

In Java 7  Types have been removed from the diamond operator on the right-hand side(RHS). My question why don't remove the complete diamond operator from RHS?
I know it will throw the warning, but Java 7 could have removed the warning too.

> - Type safety: The expression of type HashMap needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,String>
> - HashMap is a raw type. References to generic type HashMap<K,V> should be parameterized

The logic behind my thinking:
As we have already defined the map will have a string as a key and an object with Map<String, String> myMap on LHS.
With this compiler has sufficient info. So why does it throw a warning if you miss the diamond operator altogether?

I am sure there must be a reason behind it but I am not getting it.

Comment: This is the difference between type inference and raw types. As always the answer is "backwards compatibility".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code compiles and runs without error.

```
SoftReference<String> ref = new SoftReference(new Integer(1));
Object o = ref.get();
System.out.println(o); // prints "1"
```

A raw instance of `SoftReference` is created. "Raw" means that there is no generic type checking, which is required to allow to mix generics with pre-generics code.

By making the diamond operator implicit, you would break it.